# Explanation for strange pattern appear on Bath tub with sand in it

Tags: everyday-life

We have a round bathtub with a surface radius of about 15 cm or greater. It so happens that the water that came from the tab has a little sand in it. Today when the water was about half-filled, I just seen this pattern made up of sand.

[image]

At a first glance,  I haven't think too much, just put my hand inside and make the water round and round so that after a little time sand seems to sit in the middle. But After $15$ or more minutes later the same crazy pattern reappears.

So Is there any particular reason for this particular pattern to appear?

Comment: The patterns are reminiscent of Chladni patterns: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernst_Chladni So maybe some vibrations are responsible?

Comment: I think the key concept is rather that of the node/antinode. In Chladni patterns, these arise from plate vibration or stationarity; here, they arise from the convective driving force (or lack thereof) of oscillatory and reflective currents. There's a lot of literature on wave- and air-driven (*Aeolian*) ripple formation in granular materials; see [here](https://www.pmmh.espci.fr/fr/morphodynamique/papers/A57_annurev-fluid-011212-140806.pdf) and [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.538.4890&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (especially Fig. 3C), for example.